# JavaFX setting transparent node background above dynamic background

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have this dynamic background (which is just a -fx-background-color gradient):

[image]

On this background, there's a styled hbox:

[image]

And finally, my TextField node inside it:

[image]

I want to make the background of my textField transparent, although it is not possible due to the hbox background color. Is there anything I can do to bypass it?

AnchorPane gradient background css:

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top right, red, green);
```

HBox css:

```
-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

TextField css:

```
-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
-fx-border-color: blue;
-fx-border-width: 3;
-fx-border-radius: 8;
-fx-text-fill: white;
```

Comment: @jewelsea that's precisely my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by what @jewelsea suggested in his answer, I thought to give a try to his solution :). And indeed it worked perfectly well !! For that, I would like to thank @jewelsea for sharing a concept (multiple shape subtraction) which I am not so familiar at.

The general idea is to create a dedicated Pane that can drill holes for the provided list of nodes. These holes will be of same size of each node and at the location where they overlap.

To say this technically, we take a big shape(Rectangle) and clip the regions (using shape subtraction) that overlay with the provided nodes, and place this computed shape between the background and our actual nodes layout.

In the below demo, I added two columns of TextFields. Both are transparent text fields. I created a custom pane [named as `PerforatedPane` ;-)], to which I supplied only the first column TextFields. The layer clips all the regions that the Textfield(s) overlay. The pane also refills the holes when a node is removed from the list.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class PerforatedPaneDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Node> nodesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Button add = new Button("Add Row");
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            TextField textField1 = new TextField();
            textField1.getStyleClass().add("transparent-field");

            TextField textField2 = new TextField();
            textField2.getStyleClass().add("transparent-field");

            HBox row = new HBox(10, textField1, textField2);
            layout.getChildren().add(row);
            nodesList.add(textField1);
        });
        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setOnAction(e1 -> {
            int lastIndex = nodesList.size() - 1;
            nodesList.remove(lastIndex);
            layout.getChildren().remove(lastIndex);
        });

        PerforatedPane perforatedPane = new PerforatedPane(nodesList);
        StackPane container = new StackPane(perforatedPane, layout);
        VBox.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final VBox root = new VBox(new HBox(10, add, remove), container);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to right,#B3C890,#DBDFAA,#F5F0BB,#F5F0BB,#DBDFAA,#B3C890)");

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("PerforatedPaneDemo.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("PerforatedPane Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Pane that clips itself for the areas of the provided overlay nodes.
     */
    class PerforatedPane extends StackPane {
        /**
         * The sole purpose of this Rectangle is to provide the shape of this pane.
         * This is never used as clip. But used as a start/base for the shape subtraction.
         */
        private final Rectangle mainClip = new Rectangle();
        private final Rectangle subClip = new Rectangle();
        private InvalidationListener listener = p -> updateClip();

        private ObservableList<Node> nodes;

        public PerforatedPane(ObservableList<Node> nodes) {
            this.nodes = nodes;
            mainClip.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            mainClip.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
            getStyleClass().add("perforated-pane");
            setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            addListenersToNode(nodes);
            nodes.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super Node>) p -> {
                while (p.next()) {
                    if (p.getAddedSize() > 0) {
                        addListenersToNode((List<Node>) p.getAddedSubList());
                    }
                    if (p.getRemovedSize() > 0) {
                        removeListenersFromNode((List<Node>) p.getRemoved());
                    }
                }
            });
            widthProperty().addListener(listener);
            heightProperty().addListener(listener);
        }

        private void addListenersToNode(List<Node> addedNodes) {
            addedNodes.forEach(node -> {
                node.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(listener);
                node.layoutXProperty().addListener(listener);
                node.layoutYProperty().addListener(listener);
                node.translateXProperty().addListener(listener);
                node.translateYProperty().addListener(listener);
            });
            Platform.runLater(this::updateClip);
        }

        private void removeListenersFromNode(List<Node> removedNodes) {
            removedNodes.forEach(node -> {
                node.layoutBoundsProperty().removeListener(listener);
                node.layoutXProperty().removeListener(listener);
                node.layoutYProperty().removeListener(listener);
                node.translateXProperty().removeListener(listener);
                node.translateYProperty().removeListener(listener);
            });
            Platform.runLater(this::updateClip);
        }

        private void updateClip() {
            Bounds paneBounds = localToScene(getLayoutBounds());
            Shape finalClip = null;
            for (final Node node : nodes) {
                Bounds nodeBounds = node.localToScene(node.getLayoutBounds());
                if(nodeBounds.intersects(paneBounds)) {
                    subClip.setWidth(nodeBounds.getWidth());
                    subClip.setHeight(nodeBounds.getHeight());
                    subClip.setX(nodeBounds.getMinX() - paneBounds.getMinX());
                    subClip.setY(nodeBounds.getMinY() - paneBounds.getMinY());
                    if (finalClip == null) {
                        finalClip = Shape.subtract(mainClip, subClip);
                    } else {
                        finalClip = Shape.subtract(finalClip, subClip);
                    }
                }
            }
            setClip(finalClip);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS file:

```
.perforated-pane{
    -fx-background-color: #00000050;
}

.transparent-field,
.transparent-field:focused{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-color: #777777;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
 }

.transparent-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color:-fx-focus-color;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Outstanding, thank you. Just a question, I noticed that removeListenersFromNode() is only used when nodes are removed from the observable list. I'm invoking PerforatedPaneDemo passing parent.getChildren() as argument, which means that removeListenersFromNode will only be triggered if I remove a node in its parent. If I do that, all the listeners will be garbage collected within the node, so is this method really necessary?

Comment: In this case it is not necessary. I usually have a practice of removing listeners if I add them explicitly to a node elsewhere. It is up to you whether it is needed or not.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply! I was wondering if there is any way to "drill holes" in the same pane which children are in, like "Vbox root". Otherwise the only approach to do so would be using another pane (in this case, StackPane) in order to clip specific spots on it?

Comment: Clipping will not be applied at intermediate stages. It gets applied on the final rendered node. So applying it in the same container will result to clip the everything at that region, resulting you to see only holes but no TextFields :D

Comment: There's a problem, it is not possible to make the rectangles rounded. Tried setting style background-radius + border_radius and setArcWidth + setArcWidth. None works. Besides, my guess is that finalClip is messing up with the final shape format.

Comment: I think you doing something wrong. It works for me.. check the updated screenshot.

Comment: Interesting, how you've setted the corners? Through textField or rectangle?

Comment: I set them on both

Comment: I guess you setted the TextBox corners with background-radius + border_radius and Rectangle with setArcWidth + setArcWidth, is that so?

Comment: As the background color is transparent, it does'nt matter with background radius. I set the border radius of TextField and arcWidth/Height of Rectangle.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your assistance, managed to make it work, I was setting rectangle arc in mainClip, it should be subClip

Answer (score 5):

The transparency of the text field has nothing to do with the HBox background, it is only a property of the text field.

What is actually required (as confirmed by the asker), is that, for some part of the TextField (e.g. the stuff inside the blue border), the underlying portion of the HBox should also be transparent, allowing the underlying gradient in the AnchorPane to become visible.

**Clip based Solution**

You can apply a clip to the HBox to mask out the area to be made transparent. If you have multiple text fields, then you can use shape subtraction to add additional fields to the clip.

In the spirit of the question, I will not supply code for this.

Comment: I don't really get why would you not provide any code, it should be simple clipping or subtracting shapes but I'm having some trouble, it just seems not possible to do both once both my nodes are already rendered in the scene (but that's just a guess)

Comment: my initialize() method always throws NPE: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.shape.Shape.getTransformedArea()" because "<parameter1>" is null

Comment: It is not simple to write the code for this (IMO).  It is not possible to help you debug your code unless provided a [mcve].  Even with that, there is effort involved which I may not wish to undertake.

Comment: One quick note., the node (or mask) you are going to clip should be treated as a background layer only. Don't include any nodes to that layer. Otherwise the nodes will be also clipped. The textbox should be on one layer/container. And behind it a masked/clipped layer should be placed. Then you will get the desired effect.