# JavaFX crop graphics from button background

Tags: css, javafx

[image]

**Goal:** Make button's graphic (ImageView) transparent in a way that it "dig a hole" inside the button with the ImageView's image shape

**Problem:**

```
.button > .image-view {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

This code makes the button entirely orange. Setting any kind of BlendMode to the ImageView also don't work

In addition, I've tried using WritableImage in order to make every ImageView's image pixel transparent, but it also just makes the button all orange.

**No MRE?** MRE would simply be my button's fxml code, which is nothing else than a button with background-color and a ImageView as button graphic.

My best guess on how to make it work would be using some cropping technique, but I'm unable to code it as I still find cropping in JavaFX way to painful and confusing to use.

> **EDIT 1**

Following jewelsea suggestion, it kind of seems like a progress, but I can't figure out what's missing (probably it's not even being done correctly):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) button_assignColor.getGraphic(); // gets button imageView
button_assignColor.setGraphic(null); // detach imageView from button, otherwise an exception is thrown
button_assignColor.setClip(imageView); // clipping imageView shape from button?
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: [Related, but different example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774514/javafx-setting-transparent-node-background-above-dynamic-background/76784608#76784608). A clip should work here.

Comment: @jewelsea true, I tried adapting the code but I haven't managed to put that to work, also I was hoping to get a simpler alternative for this case specific, but I fear there's not

Comment: @jewelsea please check edit 1

Comment: Should be similar to the other question, you create a rectangle the same size as the button then subtract the shape of the image from the rectangle and use that  as a clip for the button.  I haven’t time to test it right now though.

Comment: You can only have a node in the scene graph once, which is why you can’t set your image view as a clip and as a graphic for the button.  To get around that you can create two image view nodes with the same image, one for the clip and one for the graphic. Not sure you really need to do that here, but it is something to know.

Comment: The issue with my suggested approach in comments is that it recommends to "subtract the shape of the image from the rectangle", but an image isn't a shape unless it can be defined as an SVGPath, so shape subtraction won't work for this.

Comment: The difficulty here is how to create an appropriate clip, which is not simple in code. Possibly it could be done via a snapshot of the original node and setting the alpha values in the clip image appropriately using a PixelWriter, rebuilding the clip whenever the node size changes. Or you could use image editing software to do take a screenshot of the button, then "subtract the shape of the image from the rectangle" and create a clip image from that, that is kind of painful.